# LIKE operator in SQL for my Access Database returns no values in ASP CLASSIC while it does if the query gets copied directly in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, sql-like

So as the title says, I'm trying to run a query in my ASP Classic page but for some reason it doesn't return a record set while it does returns a record set it if the query is copied directly in Access.

There is one thing where it probably goes wrong, namely:

- The query uses an `LIKE operator` on a `NUMERIC value`.

Obviously the `like` operator can only be used on `STRING` values so I tried to cast the `numeric` value to a `string` using `CStr`, this had no effect. Then I tried to just hard code a value in my query and in Access this **does** seem to work (even though I am using the `LIKE` operator on a `string` to find `numeric` values - it works in Access).

My code is as follows:

```
Set keywords_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")

Set keywords_cmd.ActiveConnection = con
sql = "SELECT Description, MyNumber FROM Orders where MyNumber LIKE '*23*' "

keywords_cmd.CommandText = sql

Set keywords = keywords_cmd.Execute(sql)

if keywords.EOF then
response.write("EOF???")
end if


Do While Not keywords.EOF
    response.write("A record")
%><br> <%       
keywords.movenext
Loop
```

When pasting the SQL command directly into Access it generates 6 records containing the 23 number. Though when doing the exact same in the ASP file it generates 0 records (EOF = true).

I also checked my connection to the database by adjusting the SQL command to:

```
sql = "SELECT Description, MyNumber FROM Orders where MyNumber = 1506 "
```

This generates records in the ASP file so the connection works.

So the question is: why are no records generated while they are using the exact same query in Access directly?

Just a reminder: the column `MyNumber` is of type `NUMERIC` in the database.

Some additional information: The Access database is a `mdb file` (older Access) perhaps this also has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Seems that I only had to replace the `*` wildcards with the `%` wildcard. This did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

use string function Str ( number )

```
sql = "SELECT Description, MyNumber FROM Orders where Str(MyNumber) LIKE '*23*' "
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Still returns no records. Also tried to do it like this: sql = `"SELECT Description, MyNumber FROM Orders where CStr(MyNumber) LIKE '*23*' "`

Answer (score 0):

use `%` in "LIKE" comparisons for wildcards:

```
"SELECT Description, MyNumber FROM Orders where MyNumber LIKE '%23%'"
```

Comment: Oh i now see you have found the solution yourself @Nicolas